# Android Browser - unable to change input text from white to black

Tags: android, html, css, gwt, mgwt

I have a mobile friendly web app built using GWT/mGWT.  The app has white input text boxes and dark gray input text.  However, on Android Browser, the text shows up white-on-white and is thus invisible.  All the CSS I tried fails to fix the problem

```
.my-textBox {
    color: #555 !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the colour of the text is being overwritten somewhere else in your stylesheet.

Try being more specific with your rule, such as `#container input.my-textBox { ... }`

Also, try putting the rule at the very end of your stylesheet and make sure that the stylesheet it's in is the very last stylesheet that's loaded when the browser loads the page.

Finally, make sure there's no inline CSS on the input element itself that's overriding your `color` rule.

Comment: Thanks yes I finally clued in to Inspect Element and it turned out I was styling a <div> that enclosed the <input> in question.  So I added this: .my-textBox input {...} and that properly styled the input to have a white background and black text.

Answer (score 0):

why this `*/` ????

Try

```
input [type=text]{ 
color: #555;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
}
```